Using `text-overflow: ellipsis` in a responsive table with dynamic width?
I have an extremely basic HTML <table> where some cells' content is really long.
By default, long text wraps on to multiple lines, but I want to use text-overflow: ellipsis to truncate the text at the point where it wraps, keeping it on a single line. The problem is when I use text-wrap: nowrap, the text is forced onto a single huge line and the table is forced to overflow its container and looks awful. And obviously the ellipse does not work.
The table is responsive so I can't give it or its cells a fixed width.
Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4m8ofqwu/4/
This is the table without text-wrap: nowrap:

This is what I want to achieve (ellipsis at the point where text would normally wrap):

This is what actually happens:



section {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.truncateme {
/*
  Remove the "nowrap" line to see the text wrap and the
  table return to normal width with no overflow.
  This is the width I want to achieve, but instead of the
  text wrapping on to multiple lines, I want it to break
  with an ellipsis "..." at that width.
*/
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<section>
  
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td><div class="truncateme">This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap.</div></td>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>Peach</td>
    <td>Mango</td>
    <td>Kiwi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Carrot</td>
    <td>Broccoli</td>
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>Cucumber</td>
    <td>Spinach</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Eggplant</td>
    <td>Cabbage</td>
    <td>Cauliflower</td>
    <td>Pepper</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pear</td>
    <td>Cherry</td>
    <td>Blueberry</td>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>Raspberry</td>
    <td>Melon</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Lime</td>
    <td>Coconut</td>
    <td>Papaya</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lettuce</td>
    <td>Onion</td>
    <td>Garlic</td>
    <td>Ginger</td>
    <td>Zucchini</td>
    <td>Kale</td>
    <td>Radish</td>
    <td>Beetroot</td>
    <td>Brussels Sprouts</td>
    <td>Asparagus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apricot</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
    <td>Nectarine</td>
    <td>Pomegranate</td>
    <td>Fig</td>
    <td>Avocado</td>
    <td>Guava</td>
    <td>Passion Fruit</td>
    <td>Starfruit</td>
    <td>Lychee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</section>




Try white-space: nowrap instead of text-wrap. The latter is generally more about how you wrap your lines, while the former dictates whitespace's behavior (including its ability to wrap lines).

Does this answer your question? How to stop text from taking up more than 1 line?

Are the other columns can be fixed width or they need to be dynamic too? Because if they not need to be dynamic, a simple line table-layout: fixed to ``table` and fix width all other column will help, like this

Can you find your desired width and just add that as a max-width? I think you need a forced width.

You need to take the cell contents out of the flow so that the table layout is unaffected by it. One way to do that is to use absolute positioning.
Then to make the sixth column as wide as possible, style it with width: 100%. However, this forces the other columns to be as narrow as possible, so values like “Brussels Sprouts” wrap onto two lines. Avoid this by styling every cell with white-space: nowrap.


section {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px;
}

.truncateme {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.truncateme>div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: white;
}
<section>
  
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td class="truncateme"><div>This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap.</div></td>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>Peach</td>
    <td>Mango</td>
    <td>Kiwi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Carrot</td>
    <td>Broccoli</td>
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>Cucumber</td>
    <td>Spinach</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Eggplant</td>
    <td>Cabbage</td>
    <td>Cauliflower</td>
    <td>Pepper</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pear</td>
    <td>Cherry</td>
    <td>Blueberry</td>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>Raspberry</td>
    <td>Melon</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Lime</td>
    <td>Coconut</td>
    <td>Papaya</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lettuce</td>
    <td>Onion</td>
    <td>Garlic</td>
    <td>Ginger</td>
    <td>Zucchini</td>
    <td>Kale</td>
    <td>Radish</td>
    <td>Beetroot</td>
    <td>Brussels Sprouts</td>
    <td>Asparagus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apricot</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
    <td>Nectarine</td>
    <td>Pomegranate</td>
    <td>Fig</td>
    <td>Avocado</td>
    <td>Guava</td>
    <td>Passion Fruit</td>
    <td>Starfruit</td>
    <td>Lychee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</section>




Thanks, this is great. The only problem is that it does make the cell as wide as possible, so if the long cell's text isn't super long, it will have a bunch of visible whitespace after it which could otherwise serve as useful space for the other table cells to expand into. Is there any way of making the max-width of the cell equal to the length of its text?

Not with this solution, because by using absolute positioning I have dissociated the cell contents from the table so that they no longer affect each other.

Thank you. Are there any other pure CSS solutions which might work, or will I have to get JavaScript involved to set a max-width based on the longest line in the column?

Maybe, maybe not. Have you tried some of the answers to this question? Using a CSS Grid instead of a table might give you more control. Or can you simply relax your requirements a bit?

I did try the stuff in that question; I think I will have to accept a less-than-perfect solution and/or use some JS. CSS grid would be good, but I'm making heavy use of DataTables.net for table filtering etc. so I'm stuck with real <table> markup. Thanks for your help.

Edit: You need to specify the width of the container of the text for the ellipsis to work. But you mentioned that it's a responsive table and don't want to change the cells width. But you can set the default max width of the cells so it will not span that long and so the ellipsis will work.
Add td with max-width: 300px; (you may change it depending on your need):
td {
  max-width: 300px;
}

Here is the working code:


section {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.truncateme {
/*
  Remove the "nowrap" line to see the text wrap and the
  table return to normal width with no overflow.
  This is the width I want to achieve, but instead of the
  text wrapping on to multiple lines, I want it to break
  with an ellipsis "..." at that width.
*/
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

td {
  max-width: 300px;
}
<section>
  
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td><div class="truncateme">This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap. This is a super long cell which I would like to truncate with an ellipsis instead of letting the text wrap.</div></td>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>Peach</td>
    <td>Mango</td>
    <td>Kiwi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Carrot</td>
    <td>Broccoli</td>
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>Cucumber</td>
    <td>Spinach</td>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>Eggplant</td>
    <td>Cabbage</td>
    <td>Cauliflower</td>
    <td>Pepper</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pear</td>
    <td>Cherry</td>
    <td>Blueberry</td>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>Raspberry</td>
    <td>Melon</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Lime</td>
    <td>Coconut</td>
    <td>Papaya</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lettuce</td>
    <td>Onion</td>
    <td>Garlic</td>
    <td>Ginger</td>
    <td>Zucchini</td>
    <td>Kale</td>
    <td>Radish</td>
    <td>Beetroot</td>
    <td>Brussels Sprouts</td>
    <td>Asparagus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apricot</td>
    <td>Plum</td>
    <td>Nectarine</td>
    <td>Pomegranate</td>
    <td>Fig</td>
    <td>Avocado</td>
    <td>Guava</td>
    <td>Passion Fruit</td>
    <td>Starfruit</td>
    <td>Lychee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
</section>




OP specifically said they wanted to avoid giving the cell a fixed width as it's a responsive table.

@user7290573 thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer. We can use the td max-width so if the width of the cell exceeded, it will be converted to ellipsis. The cells width will remain responsive.
